# solve by Gauss-Jordan elimination method

Tags: matrices

I am not able to solve this following problem, using Gauss-Jordan elimination method:

$$\begin{cases}x_1 -2x_2 + x_3 = 3\\
-2x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3 =2\\
-3x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 = 3 \end{cases}$$

I  would be grate if you could give me a solution.

Comment: Why can't you solve it? What goes wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Comment: you can find this method in the internet with many examples

Comment: "*...give me a solution*" is definitely not the right attitude to have asking a question here.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have read this website more carefully.I saw other examples, but I cannot solve this one.I calculated like this: R2 = R2 + 2R1 = 1 -2 1 :8 , R3 = 0 -7 5 :8 , R3 + 3R1 = 0 -7 5 : 12 →　R2 = -1/3*R2 = 0 1 -5/3 : -8/3, R3 →　1/5*R3 = 0 -7/5 1 : 12/5 And, I am stacked here. I do not know how to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In matrix representation, this equation can be modeled as:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -2 & 1 \\
        -2 & 1 & 3 \\
        -3 & -1 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2\\
        x_3
        \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
        3\\
        2\\
        3
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

To make your life easier, you can create an augmented matrix:
$$
  \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    -2 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
    -3 & -1 & 2 & 3
  \end{array}\right)
$$

Now from there, treat each row as an equation and that will allow you to perform different operations on it, such as multiply a row by a constant, add two rows, etc. The way I like doing it is ensuring the first column is $1,0,0$, then the next one is some number$,1,0$, etc. (that's the standard way, however there are many ways to do this). One such way of solving it is:
$$\begin{align}
  \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    -2 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
    -3 & -1 & 2 & 3
  \end{array}\right)&\rightarrow  R_3= R_3+3R_1\rightarrow 
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    -2 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
    0 & -7 & 5 & 12
  \end{array}\right)\\&\rightarrow  R_2= R_2+2R_1\rightarrow 
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & -3 & 5 & 8 \\
    0 & -7 & 5 & 12
  \end{array}\right)\\&\rightarrow  R_2=7R_2;R_3=-3R_3\rightarrow 
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & -21 & 35 & 56 \\
    0 & 21 & -15 & -36
  \end{array}\right)\\&\rightarrow  R_3=R_3+R_2\rightarrow 
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & -21 & 35 & 56 \\
    0 & 0 & 20 & 20
  \end{array}\right)\\&\rightarrow  R_2=-\frac{R_2}{21}\rightarrow 
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 1 & -\frac53 & -\frac83 \\
    0 & 0 & 20 & 20
  \end{array}\right)
\end{align}$$

And now you can solve it. Remember that this augmented matrix is really:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & -\frac53 \\
        0 & 0 & 20 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2\\
        x_3
        \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
        3\\
        -\frac83\\
        20
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

And therefore, we have the equations:

$$\begin{cases}x_1-2x_2+x_3=3\\x_2-\frac53x_3=-\frac83\\20x_3=20\end{cases}$$

Now solving it is really easy.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment. I have a question. Should I make all of the coefficient zero in the third row?

Comment: @Serendipity The standard way is to do that, and to make the first coefficient in the second row zero.

Comment: You can use [this](http://matrix.reshish.com/gaussSolution.php) website to see how to do it (you really don't need to create it into an identity matrix but that can work too). Actually, I made a mistake in my answer because I wrote bottom-right element as 2 and not 3. It is fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the problem. I appreciate it.